# Songs List does not display after giving permissions

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a making a music app and  have given permission the permission dialog does appear but the problem is as soon as I grant the permission the songs are not displayed.

But when I stop the app and reopen it, I can see the songs displayed.

I want to display the songs as soon as I give the  permissions.How do I achieve that

Edit: I am using a fragment

```html
    private var storagePermissions = arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    var storagePermissions13 = arrayOf(READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)

    private fun permissionsHandler(): Array<String> {
        val p: Array<String> = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {

            storagePermissions13
        } else {
            storagePermissions
        }
        return p
    }
        private var activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>> = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {result ->
            var allAreGranted = true
            for(b in result.values) {
                allAreGranted = allAreGranted && b
            }

            if(allAreGranted) {
               getMusicList()
            }
        }
            override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

       activityResultLauncher.launch(permissionsHandler())
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple with this, Check if storage or media (for android 13) permission is granted or not & if it can be asked again or not. If it can be asked again, then do it and if not then simply show a dialog with a button to redirect user to the app settings screen to grant the permission from there manually.

Here is how to do so.

```
private val storagePermission = if (isTiramisuPlus())
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
    else {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }
    private var askCount = 0

    private val permissionsLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { granted ->
            if (!granted) {
                askCount++
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                    && shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(storagePermission)
                ) {
                    askCount++
                    askForStoragePermission()
                } else {
                    showSettingsDialog()
                }
            } else {
                onPermissionGranted()
            }
        }

    private var permissionDialog: AlertDialog? = null

    private fun showSettingsDialog() {
        if (permissionDialog == null) {
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.permission_denied_title))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.allow_for_smooth))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings) { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                    val intent = Intent()
                    intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                    val uri = Uri.fromParts(
                        "package", packageName,
                        null
                    )
                    intent.data = uri
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            permissionDialog = builder.create()
            permissionDialog?.show()
        } else {
            if (permissionDialog?.isShowing == false) permissionDialog?.show()
        }
    }

    private fun askForStoragePermission() {
        permissionsLauncher.launch(storagePermission)
    }

    private fun storagePermissionGranted() = storagePermission.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            storagePermission
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
```

**Using this code, you'll be able to grant and handle the result of the permission, then put permission related logic in `onResume` and load your music files accordingly whenever the permission is granted.**

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!storagePermissionGranted()) {
            if (askCount == 0)
                askForStoragePermission()
            else if (askCount == 2) {
                showSettingsDialog()
            }
            return
        } else {
            askCount = 2
            if (permissionDialog?.isShowing == true)
                permissionDialog?.dismiss()
            onPermissionGranted()
        }
    }
```

**You have the `onPermissionGranted()` method to put your loading logic into.**

```
private fun onPermissionGranted() {
            //Your music files loading logic here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try putting your getMusicList() inside the onRequestPermissionsResult:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted, update the song list here
        } else {
            // Permission denied, handle the error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this method has been deprecated

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui it has not in the Activity. Check for a fragment alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for your purpose:

```
private var storagePermissions = arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
var storagePermissions13 = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)

private fun permissionsHandler(): Array<String> {
    val p: Array<String> = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        storagePermissions13
    } else {
        storagePermissions
    }
    return p
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!,permissionsHandler(),1)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    //Check if permission is granted
    if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Call the function to get the music list
        getMusicList()
    }
}
```

You need to slightly modify your code. As you can see, in the above code, you have to put the `getMusicList()` function inside the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` function. The `onRequestPermissionsResult()` function is called as soon as the user gives permission. So, by putting your `getMusicList()` function inside `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, you can get the songs as soon as permission is given.

**Edit:**

`onRequestPermissionsResult()` is deprecated in `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`. So, for fragments, the `registerForActivityResult()` function has to be used. Example code:

```
//Check if permission is granted
val requestPermLaunch = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
    if (isGranted) {
        //Run code if permission is granted
        getMusicList()
    } else {
        //Run code if permission is not granted
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission has not been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

//Launch the read external storage permission
private fun startLocationPermissionRequest() {
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
}
```

Comment: Hello @Dinux isn't the method onRequestPermissionResult deprecated I want this to achieve with registerForResult method

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui I have edited my answer to include the method using `registerForActivityResult()`. Please check.